# Azure ML failed to deploy endpoint

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, conda, azure-machine-learning-service

### Problem Description

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/02/deploy-your-ml-model-as-a-web-service-in-microsoft-azure-cloud/) to deploy an ML model to Azure ML as a web service.

The model has been uploaded successfully (Image 1), but it failed when I created the web service endpoint (Image 2).

[image: Image 1: succeeded model upload]

[image: Image 2: failed endpoint deployment]

I am new to cloud computing and still confused about how to troubleshoot this issue. The "Deployment logs" tab only contained short information as below.

```
container "predict" in pod "wk-caas-f62cbd87d3e3400a8fffc23a20f0744e-8c212518c5f6b7404584eb194515f3a1-pod" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

Here are the model and source codes I used in the deployment:

- [Model](https://github.com/mari-bangkit/prediction-model/blob/main/regressor.pkl)
- [Entry script](https://github.com/mari-bangkit/prediction-model/blob/main/scoring.py)
- [Conda environment YAML](https://github.com/mari-bangkit/prediction-model/blob/main/conda_env.yml)
- [Deployment logs](https://pastebin.com/nUy8YGyh)

### Question

Any advice to solve this issue?

Comment: It is the first model I deployed, and I used Azure Container Instance in "Compute type" instead of AKS.

Comment: Could something like workspace regions have an effect?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with YAML file contents.

For every web service the end point configuration will cause the issue. The three main patterns using which we can create a YAML file are mentioned below.

[@rsethur](https://github.com/rsethur), [@alexbuckgit](https://github.com/alexbuckgit), [@Blackmist](https://github.com/Blackmist), [@mx-iao](https://github.com/mx-iao) worked on the similar scenario and presented the findings in their official blog.

- YAML: basic
- YAML: system-assigned identity
- YAML: user-assigned identity

Comment: I have tried some of the YAML arrangements by @rsethur, but it still doesn't work. 

Here is what my conda YAML file looks like now (I also changed the name to "conda_dependencies.yml"): https://pastebin.com/G7wN686a.

I cannot find what you mention "official blog" and just search around their GitHub with the keyword "yml" to find a similar YAML dependencies file.

May you mention the blog URL explicitly, please?

Comment: @ammfat - where do we even find the yaml for deployment?

Comment: @JanzaibMBaloch, it seems that the content on Pastebin has expired. Unfortunately, I didn't save the YAML anywhere else. However, I host the 'working one' in this repository: https://github.com/mari-bangkit/prediction-model.